# Push update to web page B from web page A

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to build a web page (A) with some text input fields and a button.
When I push the button, the info entered is automatically updated on page B.
I think AJAX and Jquery can do that... but I am struggling to find specific instructions to build such thing.
(this is going to be used in medical simulation. The learners will have a tablet open on page B, which will be styled to look like a vital sign monitor. I want to be able to send new values on the fly from another device)
I just need a point in the right direction.
Thank you

Comment: You will need a database like mySQL and a server language like php
With jQuery Ajax

Comment: Something like: Page A = php page/form sends data to file in mySQL database.
Page B = Ajax/jquery code to get info from file in database as it is updated.